# Broadcast event from Angular web app and receive in IONIC application

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, observable, inappbrowser

I am having an IONIC application that consumes my Angular web application using InAppBrowser. I want to trigger an event from Angular web application and open camera from the IONIC application. Currently, I am using InAppBrowser to open my Angular web application.
Can anyone suggest to me what is the best way to achieve this?

I tried postMessage, Event, window.addEventListener but didn't get success

I need to integrate my current angular web application in IONIC mobile application and use the Cordova plugin with The angular web application.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to implement postCordovaMessage that must be available for InAppBrowser windows created with Cordova.

Add message listener in Your APP:

```
const browser = this.inAppBrowser.create('https://.....');
browser.on('message').subscribe(event => {
     if (message.data.action === 'openCamera') {
          // open camera
     }
});
```

Send message in Your WEB:

```
var message = {action: 'openCamera'};
if (webkit.messageHandlers.cordova_iab) { 
     webkit.messageHandlers.cordova_iab.postMessage(JSON.stringify(message));
}
```

If Your WEB page just need to capture image for WEB page functionality then You can try to use HTML5 capture attribute for input element:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture >
```